# Stop postback after alert by javascript in ASP.NET Code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, alert

I have a textbox and a button, on button's clientClick I call javascript function and there is also server side coding.

Problem is, the page gets post back even if I have return False in the javascript.

Here is my javascript function:

```
function checkALphaNumericFormat(str) {

            //get previous value before editing
            var txtUserId = document.getElementById('<%=txtUserId.ClientID%>');            
            var userId = txtUserId.value;
            var patternAlphaNumeric = /^[A-z0-9]+$/gi;
            var match = userId.match(patternAlphaNumeric);

            //Check Null values
            if (txtUserId.value != null && txtUserId.value != "") {

                //Check for AlphaNumeric values for User Id
                if (match == null) {
                    alert("Please provide valid AlphaNumeric User Id");
                    return false  ;
                }

                return false ;
            }
            else {
                    alert("User Id field should not be null");
                    return false  ;               
            }              
            return false ;
        }
```

and I am calling this function on my Form as:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCreate"  CssClass="loginButton" style="margin:0px 0px 1px 30px;" OnClientClick ="return checkALphaNumericFormat(this.value);"  Text="CREATE" />
```

Comment: plz provide the button designer where u r calling the on client click

Comment: call your method like this `OnClientClick="return checkALphaNumericFormat(...`

Comment: Thanks guys for the information, I am calling it as <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCreate" CssClass="loginButton" style="margin:0px 0px 1px 30px;" OnClientClick ="return checkAlphaNumericFormat(this.value);" Text="CREATE" />  
Thanks for your replys. The issue is now solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to call JavaScript function as below:

```
OnClientClick="if(!validateform()){return false;}
```

where `validateform()` should be your java script function. Your java script function should have  `return = true;` at the end of function in successfull execution, like in below function:

```
function validateform()
{
  var txtSearch = document.getElementById('<%=txtKeywordSearch.ClientID%>')
  if(txtSearch.value == '')
  {
  alert('No Search Creatria Selected!');
  return false;
  }
return true; 
}
```

Please try and let me know if it works for you.

Thanks,
Harish

Comment: Hi Harish,
Yes this code also works :) Thanks although we can use return checkAlphaNumericFormat(this.value) as this also works.

I have found the bottle, it got stuck at other javascript function.

Thanks for your help

Comment: welcome user2126933 and thanks to let me know the other way to call the function.